# File metadata such as time in Azure Storage from Databricks

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-databricks

I m trying to get creationfile metadata.

File is in: ***Azure Storage***
Accesing data throw: ***Databricks***

right now I m using:

```py
   file_path = my_storage_path
   dbutils.fs.ls(file_path)
```

but it returns

```
[FileInfo(path='path_myFile.csv', name='fileName.csv', size=437940)]
```

I do not have any information about creation time, there is a way to get that information ?

other solutions in Stackoverflow are refering to files that are already in databricks
[Does databricks dbfs support file metadata such as file/folder create date or modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745924/does-databricks-dbfs-support-file-metadata-such-as-file-folder-create-date-or-mo)
in my case we access to the data from Databricks but the data are in Azure Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the version of Databricks Runtime (DBR) that you're using.  For example, modification timestamp is available if you use DBR 10.2 (didn't test with 10.0/10.1, but definitely not available on 9.1):

[image]

If you need to get that information you can use [Hadoop FileSystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) via Py4j gateway, like this:

```py
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

fs = FileSystem.get(URI("/tmp"), Configuration())

status = fs.listStatus(Path('/tmp/'))
for fileStatus in status:
    print(f"path={fileStatus.getPath()}, size={fileStatus.getLen()}, mod_time={fileStatus.getModificationTime()}")
```

Comment: the second part worked to me the Py4j gateway ! thanks :)