# List all file names located in an Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

**I want to list in Databricks all file names located in an Azure Blob Storage.**

My Azure Blob Storage is structured like this:

```
aaa
<br/>------bbb
<br/>------------bbb1.xml
<br/>------------bbb2.xml
<br/>------ccc
<br/>------------ccc1.xml
<br/>------------ccc2.xml
<br/>------------ccc3.xml
```

If I do:

```
dbutils.fs.ls('wasbs://xxx@xxx.blob.core.windows.net/aaa')
```

only subfolders bbb and ccc are listed like this:

```
[FileInfo(path='wasbs://xxx@xxx.blob.core.windows.net/aaa/bbb/', name='bbb/', size=0), 
 FileInfo(path='wasbs://xxx@xxx.blob.core.windows.net/aaa/ccc/', name='ccc/', size=0)]
```

I want to deepen to the last subfolder to see all file names located in aaa: `bbb1.xml`, `bbb2.xml`, `ccc1.xml`, `ccc2.xml` and `ccc3.xml`.

If I do:

```
dbutils.fs.ls('wasbs://xxx@xxx.blob.core.windows.net/aaa/*')
```

an error occurs because the path can not be parameterized.

Any idea to do this in Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

`dbutils.fs.ls` doesn't support wildcards, that's why you're getting an error. You have few choices:

1. Use [Python SDK for Azure blob storage to list files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) - it could be faster than using recursive `dbutils.fs.ls`, but you will need to setup authentication, etc.
2. You can do recursive calls to `dbutils.fs.ls`, using function like this, but it's not very performant:

```py
def list_files(path, max_level = 1, cur_level=0):
  """
  Lists files under the given path, recursing up to the max_level
  """
  d = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
  for i in d:
    if i.name.endswith("/") and i.size == 0 and cur_level < (max_level - 1):
      yield from list_files(i.path, max_level, cur_level+1)
    else:
      yield i.path
```

3. You can use Hadoop API to access files in your container, [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849676/file-metadata-such-as-time-in-azure-storage-from-databricks/70852702#70852702).