# How do I get file metadata using Databricks Connect?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I am using Azure Databricks, which I have hooked up to a data lake and I want to get metadata such as modified date for the files in the lake. I am able to do this within Databricks itself using `os.stat()` as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59751771/10821548), but I am developing locally using Databricks connect, and can't figure out how to test it locally given it only has context of my local file system.

Comment: You might wanna use Databricks-CLI to test your code locally. See this official documentation - https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html. Hopefully, that should solve your use case.

Comment: What is the issue? You're still connected to the cluster and the data lake is still accessible through the /dbfs/... path

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I can run `os.stat("/dbfs...")` in databricks and it gives me what I want but locally the exact same thing gives me FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '/dbfs...'. Changing the path in stat to a file that is on my local machine gives returns without error too

Comment: Can You Share a full path (you can mask some of the fields, I just want to see the pattern)?

Comment: Sure. Something like this `os.stat("/dbfs/mnt/lake/raw/api/")`

Comment: Got it. I'll have to test it tomorrow

Comment: `os.stat` won't work with db-connect because it's executed on driver, and with db-connect, driver is the local machine, not databricks